# Send GraphQL Introspection Request on WSO2

Tags: graphql, wso2, wso2-api-manager, introspection

For GraphQL APIs in WSO2, does WSO2 support GraphQL introspection ? How can we try to do GraphQL introspection requests to bypass the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the GraphQL implementation in WSO2 API Gateway, we allow only query/mutation operations through the gateway as the gateway provides QOS (operational level security, throttling and analytics) for the operations available at requested query. The above error returns because the provided query has not been included any operations but, gateway validates the operation availability on the query

Here, the application developer/ API developer already knows what types are available in the GraphQL backend as they already have the type system in the SDL file. Introspection is needed if they haven't idea on the available graphql types in the backend and  hence GraphQL provide introspection capability to retreive them by querying the __schema field.

Comment: our frontend team wants to use this thing for graphql codegen.
their question is;
There is an endpoint that returns the schema and has fixed token auth: `https://<our-hostname>/api/am/store/v1/apis/<our-api-id>/graphql-schema`
But it has the wrong Content-Type Header (it says it returns `json`, but it doesn’t)
If the Content-Type Header would be fixed (not sure what the correct one would be, maybe `application/graphql`?), we should be able to use it in our frontend build process

Comment: The REST API you mentioned ( GET  https://<our-hostname>/api/am/store/v1/apis/<our-api-id>/graphql-schema) is to get the content of the SDL schema. We haven't sent any request to GraphQL backend this time; Its what you have uploaded to APIM Publisher while creating the GraphQL API. The rest call uses "application/json" to retreive content from APIM devportal.

Comment: For the gateway requests; which are associated with your GraphQL
backend; you have to use "application/graphql" as content type, if you directly pass the query. Also you can use "application/json",  by constructing the payload as
{
  "query": "...",
  "operationName": "...",
  "variables": { "myVariable": "someValue", ... }
}

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to retreive type system, you can use **GET https:///api/am/store/v1/apis//graphql-schema** rest API which is passed to get the SDL as a string. To build it from FrontEnd, You can try something as following.

```
const sdlSchema = `type Author {
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
  }
  type Query {
    author(id: Int!): Author
  }
`;

const graphqlSchemaObj = buildSchema(sdlSchema);
```

Note: Here SDL schema be retreived using (GET https:///api/am/store/v1/apis//graphql-schema)

Comment: Follow: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v2/devportal-v2/#tag/APIs/paths/~1apis~1{apiId}~1graphql-schema/get